# Windows shell integration command is not working, possible syntax error

Tags: windows, shell, shell-extensions

I want to create a shell extension to run [shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/) apps in a local process on a Windows 7 Professional 64 bit. I need a command like `R -e "shiny::runApp('~/shinyapp')"` as defined [in the shiny tutorial webpage](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#run-and-debug). I usually create a directory called `shiny` in every data folder I have. So the supposed command should be always sth like: `R -e "shiny::runApp('%1'/shiny) for me."`

So I created a key named "Shine!" and a subkey named "command" in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell with a value `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\x64\R.exe -e "shiny::runApp('%1/shiny')"` The dir structure in regedit is as below:

[image]

Now, whenever I right-click the data folder (containing the shiny folder) and click "Shine!", an R console (a cmd console) opens and closes, but the app is not working (the apps are thoroughly checked and working, I also checked the regedit command in cmd).

To be honest, I don't know C, windows shell or any MSDN stuff. I checked [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/382291/664404), [links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [documents](http://www.kbcafe.com/articles/HowTo.Shell.pdf), but preferred to come up with a simple solution with no error checking (missing folder, etc).

I think I'm missing a syntax error here, so I tried several versions such as only `'%1'` and right-clicking the shiny folder, also versions like `'/'%1/'/shiny'` etc. What is wrong and more importantly, how can I debug a right-click with the %1 thing, while the cmd window is closing as quick as hell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%1 is expanded by the Windows shell to the name of the folder you right-clicked.

So, if the command you want to execute is:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\x64\R.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('%1/shiny')"
```

you can replace it with a call to cmd.exe that remains open after execution and preserves the double-quotes (by doubling them inside an extra pair of double quotes), so you can check the r.exe's command output:

```
cmd /k " ""C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\x64\R.exe"" -e ""shiny::runApp('%1/shiny')"" "
```

I have no experience with R, but my guess is that the runApp command deals badly with the backslashes in the Windows path, or that it contains a space, and I also guess that "~" works with the current directory, as Windows doesn't have a real $HOME directory.

The solution for that is to chain a CD command and the R.exe call via cmd.exe:

```
cmd /c " cd /d ""%~1"" & ""C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\x64\R.exe"" -e ""shiny::runApp('~/shiny')"" "
```

(cmd /c closes the new window, cmd /k keeps it open after exectution, so the last example closes the window after launching R.exe).

Comment: You are probably right about the Windows path error, but I couldn't make the `cmd /k` work with the quotes. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8714013/664404) says the correct format for /k switch is sth like `cmd /k "code"`. I tried `cmd /k "'C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\R.exe' -e "shiny::runApp('%1')""` but didn't work also. I tried to escape the double quote with ^ or "" according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7760545/664404). Could you provide any more examples?

Comment: Enclosing sth in quotes in double quotes means using triple quotes around many things. So, now `cmd /c "cd %1 & """C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\x64\R.exe""" -e """shiny::runApp("'shiny'")""""` works but /c switch doesn't close the cmd window. It doesn't hurt actually, it's good enough that I don't need to type the whole thing, but is there any trick to close the cmd window?

Answer (score 0):

Use ProcessMonitor to determine exact arguments and working directory of R started.
When you get these values - you can setup your debugger with same settings.

Comment: You mean [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/tr-tr/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), right? I tried it and filtered Process Name: Rterm.exe. Whenever I right-click "Shine!", the process number increases by ~3600. I'll try to learn this tool but for now it seems to be an overkill for me.

Comment: Why you talking about Rterm.exe when you running R.exe? Filter output by operation. It will be "Start Process" as I can remember ("operation" - "contains" - "process"). This will give you short list easy to analyze.

Comment: Oh I see, operation contains Process start, and then properties shows all the environment and command line etc.. I'm still searching for the right syntax though.